# Input id for get address. SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, task

I would like to say right away that I use a translator, because I speak only Russian, but a little bit of English.

I recently got a job, and it was supposed that I would need to do some simple queries in SQL.

But, something went wrong and my confidence that I knew at least something was lost.  And I wouldn't want to lose my job.

**TASK:
My employer told me to make a task that sounds like this:
The id comes in, you need to enter it and get the client's address.**

---

I thought this task is being done with PL / SQL since my employer is using Oracle.  Or is it done using SQL without knowledge of the PL / SQL programming language?

Also, please tell me if there is a difference between functions, procedures, cursors that are used in SQL and those in PL / SQL?

I ask this question because my employer told me to read about them, and when I was looking for an opportunity and a hint to do this task, I came across the fact that these topics are covered in PL / SQL.

Unfortunately, I have not read the site rules yet, as there is simply no time for everything, but if you can use links to resources or books here, please direct me.

Sorry if my question, task and story were not clear to you.

As soon as I figure out everything, I will take up learning English, in order to be not only a part of the world, but also a full member of this community.

All the best to you. Hugged.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Question is too broad.  Not sure anyone can help you w/o more details.  SO Is not a tutorial site.  If you google "Oracle PL/SQL"  there are many, many tutorials.  If you then have a specific question, please edit this question with the details, or post a new question if this one gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Oracle 10g is an old piece of software, I like its [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage) page so I suggest you have look at it. (Of course, feel free to read documentation related to your database version).

In its "Most popular" section, read

- **Concepts** book first to see what Oracle is
- **SQL Reference** to learn SQL commands
- **PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference** to see what PL/SQL is (if you learn SQL properly, it'll be easier to learn PL/SQL)
- **Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals** which will be, I presume, *ultra-useful*

---

As of a task you got: that would be a **function** which accepts ID as a parameter and returns the address. I don't have your tables so I'll use Scott's sample schema and its `EMP` table to illustrate it - I'll pass employee number and return its job.

```
SQL> select * from emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81      10000                    10
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

SQL> create or replace function f_emp (par_empno in emp.empno%type)
  2    return emp.job%type
  3  is
  4    retval emp.job%type;
  5  begin
  6    select e.job
  7      into retval
  8      from emp e
  9      where e.empno = par_empno;
 10
 11    return retval;
 12
 13  exception
 14    when no_data_found then
 15      return 'No such employee';
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_emp(7782) result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MANAGER

SQL>
```

Comment: It would be more beneficial for him to figure out how to write this on his own. He said he's just starting in this field. I think he asked for guidance not full solution to his task.

Comment: This *is* just a guide, with link to documentation, suggestion what to read, and an example of how it might be done. I don't have their tables nor data, so *nothing* matches and can't be run "as is", but will help A LOT to see how to do it. Though, thank you for the comment, @Stefan.

Answer (score 1):

The translation is clear.

PL/SQL is Procedural Language for SQL (PL/SQL).

In simplest terms (which I think will help you understand as a beginner):

- Procedures are used to insert, update, delete, select data from table or tables.
- Functions are used to return a **value**.

In your case I would create a **procedure** that has ID parameter and in the procedure i would query (*select*) the data from the table using the parameter as a condition using PL/SQL.